# Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` is a string

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to connect MongoDB Atlas to my application and ran into this error when trying to run the mongoose.connect(), which is located in *db.js* (last code in the question). *process.env.MONGO_URI* seems to be interpreted as undefined and not string, giving the following error: "MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string."

this is the my *config.env*, in which I copy pasted the MONGO_URI from the Atlas.

```
MONGO_URI = mongodb+srv://kpae:XXXX@practice.xujsvaf.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

this is *app.js*, where I believe I set up the basics to run the program.

```
const express = require('express')
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
const connectDB = require('./config/db')

dotenv.config({ path: '.config/config.env' })

connectDB()

const app = express()


const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

app.listen(
    PORT, 
    console.log(`Server running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode on port ${PORT}`)
)
```

this is *db.js*

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const connectDB = async () => {
    try {
        const conn = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
            useFindAndModify: false
        })

        console.log(`MongoDB Connected: ${conn.connection.host}`)
    } catch (err) {
        //console.log('this is an error')
        console.error(err)
        process.exit(1)
    }
}


module.exports = connectDB
```

[image]

I'm having trouble pinpointing where the bug lies in my code because it seems like my files are in the root folder and MONGO_URI looks like a string. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try once like this in your env file?

```
MONGO_URI='mongodb+srv://kpae:XXXX@practice.xujsvaf.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
```

Comment: I have already tried the single quotation marks but still not working. Still, thank you.